# Is there a way I can see which hat someone else is wearing?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014, winter-bash

Some of the hats people are using with their DP's look really awesome, so is there a way I can see and view which hat it is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visit their profile, click on the number next to the little snowflake icon, and then click on the specific hat you want to view the details about it.

You can also try to find it on the [Winterbash site](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/), but secret hats won't appear there until you've earned them.

Answer (score 4):

I have a handy [userscript for this at Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/5056/hat-overflow-show-number-of-winterbash-hats-at-a-glance).

It updates most user cards like so:

[image: updated usercard]